# Magento Extensions Installation Readiness Check Error

Tags: php, magento, magento2

We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail

```
Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/module-shared-catalog 100.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/module-shared-catalog[100.0.2].
- magento/module-shared-catalog 100.0.2 requires magento/module-advanced-checkout 100.2.* -> no matching package found.
Problem 2
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.0.0].
- magento/module-review-analytics 100.2.0 requires magento/framework 101.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.0-rc21, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc30, 101.0.0, 101.0.1, 101.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.0-rc21, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.0-rc22, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.0-rc23, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.0-rc30, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.0, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.2, 100.0.2].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.0.0 requires magento/framework 100.0.2 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2].
- Installation request for magento/module-review-analytics 100.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-review-analytics[100.2.0].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .
```

--- I'm using magento 2. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there are several problems according to your log.

First: try to install your packages one by one.

Second: the  first problem is due to not found package, so check it is existing before inserting it in your composer file.

Third: other problems are due to not required dependencies that you should first add to composer. So check dependencies before.